# Exchange server cuts off 2 characters after equal in html mail

Tags: php, email, exchange-server

Viewing the source of HTML email in Outlook, I can see that the HTML is broken, e.g.:

```
<p style=argin instead of <p style="margin
```

or

```
<a href=ttp instead of <a href="http
```

Exchange (version 2003) cuts off two characters after '=' while, e.g. GMAIL does not mingle the message.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by removing:
**Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable**
header.

The more information at [WIKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable)

The original email had base64 encoded file attachment. 
(With The following headers:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf; name="Data_wp.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
```

...)